# google-cloud-sdk .bash.inc not found after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, google-cloud-platform, macos-catalina

I am encountering the following messages after upgrading to macOS Catalina on my terminal whenever I start up a new terminal:

```
/Users/<myname>/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc:3: = not found
/Users/<myname>/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc:56: command not found: complete
/Users/<myname>/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc:81: command not found: complete
/Users/<myname>/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc:82: command not found: complete
```

I have re-run the `./install.sh` command and `gcloud` commands work fine. How do I remove the above messages, or is there something else that is still missing?

EDIT:

Upgraded to macOS 10.15.4 and installed google-cloud-sdk is from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos), the macOS 64-bit version.

Comment: Which version of Catalina did you upgrade to? Also, what's the Cloud SDK you have installed?

Comment: @rsalinas Included the infor in my edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the fact that Cloud SDK is assuming that you are using bash while Catalina now uses Zsh by default as mentioned [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/444596/how-to-change-the-default-shell-to-bash-in-macos-catalina/). You may be able to remove the error by changing to bash by following the instructions over the link I shared, however, I can not test this out at the moment.

I also recommend you to report this issue to Google directly over at [their issue reporting page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so it can be reviewed and corrected if possible.

Additionally, make sure that you are using the latest Cloud SDK version by running the [`gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) so that you can better report this on the issue.

I hope you find this information useful.

Answer (score 11):

I solved the same issue by following the instruction: https://gist.github.com/dwchiang/10849350. Simply, change the `path.bash.inc` into `path.zsh.inc` in `~/.bash_profile`, same as the `completion.zsh.inc`.